# Parsing jsot with eclipse: 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, json, eclipse

My problem is parsing 2d arrays and to fix the erros. Belowe is my jason file, java code and a list of errors.

This is my Json file:`[

   {

        "elementaryProductId":1,
        "bonusMalus":30,
        "deductible":500,
        "comprehensive":1,
        "partial":0,
        "legacyPremium":130,
        "product":{

            "productId":2,
            "garage":"true",
            "constructionYear":1990,
            "region":"East",
            "dateOfBirthYoungest":"1983-06-22",
            "objectValue":25000,
            "type":"Car"
        }
    },`

And this is my java code, i think that the problem is with defining a second array:

```
    try {

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(reader);


        Iterator i = jsonArray.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()){

        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) i.next();

        .
        .
        .


       JSONArray productArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse("product");


        Iterator j = productArray.iterator();

        while (j.hasNext())
        {
            JSONObject product = (JSONObject) j.next();

             long productId = (Long) product.get("productId");
             System.out.println("The id is: " + productId);


        }`
```

List of errors:`Unexpected character (p) at position 0.
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
    at com.domain.project.SveUMain.main(SveUMain.java:66)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the error is coming from this line:

```
JSONArray productArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse("product");
...
Unexpected character (p) at position 0.
```

That line of code is going to try to parse the string "product" as if it were a JSON string. It's not, of course, so the parser bails out complaining about the very first character.

If you're trying to access the "product" field of each JSON object, you could do it like this:

```
Iterator i = jsonArray.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()){
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) i.next();
    JSONObject productObj = (JSONObject) object.get("product");
```

JSON.simple doesn't appear to have a function that would return the product objects from each object in the array with one call.

Answer (score 0):

This json file has a Syntax error.

When you try to validate the file inside an online editor, then it should give you an syntax error on line 1.

A json file starts with an object "{" then inside this you can use your array.

Also the last "," is wrong, because there is no element afterwards. (And you need to close the array "]" and the object "}".

Here are two examples which could be your correct json file.

```
{
  "elementaryProductId":1,
  "bonusMalus":30,
  "deductible":500,
  "comprehensive":1,
  "partial":0,
  "legacyPremium":130,
  "product":{
      "productId":2,
      "garage":"true",
      "constructionYear":1990,
      "region":"East",
      "dateOfBirthYoungest":"1983-06-22",
      "objectValue":25000,
      "type":"Car"
  }
}
```

And thats the second solution:

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "elementaryProductId": 1,
      "bonusMalus": 30,
      "deductible": 500,
      "comprehensive": 1,
      "partial": 0,
      "legacyPremium": 130,
      "product": {
        "productId": 2,
        "garage": "true",
        "constructionYear": 1990,
        "region": "East",
        "dateOfBirthYoungest": "1983-06-22",
        "objectValue": 25000,
        "type": "Car"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is elements afterwards it's just part of file.